# How to upload video on youtube with api key?

Tags: android, video, upload, key, android-youtube-api

I am using [yt-direct-lite-android](https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-android) to upload video. 
I have API key from https://console.developers.google.com and YouTube Data API is enabled. App on all devices uploading(no) in single channel. Can't understand where is error. Server don't send errors in logcat(json format).

**Code:**

```
public class UploadToYoutubeTask extends ATask {
    private static final String TAG = UploadToYoutubeTask.class.getName();

    /**
     * Change video privacy settings.
     * Variants: public/private/unlisted
     * https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/157177?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en-GB
     */
    public static final String PRIVACY_STATUS = "unlisted";
    public static final String PARTS = "snippet,status,contentDetails";

    /**
     * MIME type
     */
    private static String VIDEO_FILE_FORMAT = "video/*";
    public static final String DEFAULT_KEYWORD = "ytdl";
    public static final String[] SCOPES = {YouTubeScopes.YOUTUBE_UPLOAD};

    private static final String API_KEY = "AIzaSyC8S8sn4RW4mH07SfX..";

    File file;

    public UploadToYoutubeTask(File file) {
        super(TYPE);
        this.file = file;
        this.file = new File("/sdcard/..../20170826_101501_-110474017.mp4");
    }

    @Override
    public int onBackgroundWork() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBackgroundWork: " + this);

        HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
//        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new AndroidJsonFactory(); // GsonFactory
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

        final GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                App.get().getApplicationContext(),
                Arrays.asList(SCOPES));
//        credential.setSelectedAccountName("blablaname@gmail.com");
        credential.setSelectedAccount(new Account(
                "blablaname@gmail.com",
                App.get().getPackageName()));
        credential.setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());
        HttpRequestInitializer initializer = new HttpRequestInitializer() {
            @Override
            public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
                credential.initialize(request);
                request.setLoggingEnabled(true);
//                request.setIOExceptionHandler(new HttpBackOffIOExceptionHandler(new ExponentialBackOff()));
            }
        };

        YouTube.Builder youtubeBuilder = new YouTube.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, initializer);
//        YouTube.Builder youtubeBuilder = new YouTube.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, credential);
//        YouTube.Builder youtubeBuilder = new YouTube.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, null);
        youtubeBuilder.setApplicationName(App.get().getString(R.string.app_name));
        youtubeBuilder.setYouTubeRequestInitializer(new YouTubeRequestInitializer(API_KEY));
        YouTube youtube = youtubeBuilder.build();

        String videoId = tryUpload(
                youtube,
                file,
                "test title",
                "test descrioption",
                new String[]{DEFAULT_KEYWORD});

        Log.d(TAG, "onBackgroundWork: videoId=" + videoId);


        return getStatus();
    }

    public String tryUpload(YouTube youtube, File file, String title, String description, String[] tags) {
        String videoId = null;

        try {
            Video videoObjectDefiningMetadata = new Video();
            videoObjectDefiningMetadata.setStatus(new VideoStatus().setPrivacyStatus(PRIVACY_STATUS));

            VideoSnippet snippet = new VideoSnippet();
            snippet.setTitle(title);
            snippet.setDescription(description);
            snippet.setTags(Arrays.asList(tags));
            videoObjectDefiningMetadata.setSnippet(snippet);

            YouTube.Videos.Insert videoInsert = youtube.videos().insert(
                    PARTS,
                    videoObjectDefiningMetadata,
                    getMediaContent(file))
                    .setKey(API_KEY);

            MediaHttpUploader uploader = videoInsert.getMediaHttpUploader();
            uploader.setDirectUploadEnabled(false);

            MediaHttpUploaderProgressListener progressListener = new MediaHttpUploaderProgressListener() {
                public void progressChanged(MediaHttpUploader uploader) throws IOException {
                    Log.d(TAG, "progressChanged: " + uploader.getUploadState());
                    switch (uploader.getUploadState()) {
                        case INITIATION_STARTED:
                            break;
                        case INITIATION_COMPLETE:
                            break;
                        case MEDIA_IN_PROGRESS:
                            break;
                        case MEDIA_COMPLETE:
                        case NOT_STARTED:
                            Log.d(TAG, "progressChanged: upload_not_started");
                            break;
                    }
                }
            };
            uploader.setProgressListener(progressListener);

            Log.d(TAG, "Uploading..");
            Video returnedVideo = videoInsert.execute();
            Log.d(TAG, "Video upload completed");
            videoId = returnedVideo.getId();
            Log.d(TAG, String.format("videoId = [%s]", videoId));
        } catch (final GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException availabilityException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException", availabilityException);
        } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException userRecoverableException) {
            Log.i(TAG, String.format("UserRecoverableAuthIOException: %s",
                    userRecoverableException.getMessage()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException", e);
        }

        return videoId;
    }

    private AbstractInputStreamContent getMediaContent(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
        InputStreamContent mediaContent = new InputStreamContent(
                VIDEO_FILE_FORMAT,
                new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)));
        mediaContent.setLength(file.length());

        return mediaContent;
    }

}
```

**LogCat:**

```
UserRecoverableAuthIOException: null
UploadToYoutubeTask: onBackgroundWork: videoId=null
```

**build.gradle:**

> dependencies {
>       compile "com.google.code.gson:gson:${rootProject.gsonVersion}"
>       compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0')
>       compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev183-1.22.0'
>       compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.4'
>       compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2'
>       compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2' }